# ExtJS — Organizing files under app/

Tags: extjs, build

We have application classes `X`, `Y`, and `Z` where `Y` extends `X`, and `Z` extends `Y`.

`X` is in file `X.js`.
`Y` is in file `Y.js`.
`Z` is in file `Application.js` (i.e. the standard ExtJS).

We also have a large company with developers of varying skills, some who we don't want to directly expose `X.js` and `Y.js`.

For illustration, assume these are the files:

`X.js`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.X', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    name: 'X',
    launch: function () {
        // Cool stuff
    }
    // More cool stuff
});
```

`Y.js`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Y', {
    extend: 'MyApp.X',
    name: 'Y',
    launch: function () {
        // Call the parent X to set up
        this.callParent(arguments);
        // Cool stuff
    }
    // More cool stuff
});
```

`Application.js`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Z', {
    extend: 'MyApp.Y',
    name: 'Z',
    launch: function () {
        // Call the parent Y to set up
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

The `app/` directory looks like this:

```
app/
    model/
    store/
    view/
        X.js
        Y.js
        Application.js
```

The company would like `X.js` and `Y.js` out of direct sight, so that basically other developers will see just `Application.js`:

```
app/
    model/
    store/
    view/
    Application.js
```

So a few questions:

1) Can I put `X.js` and `Y.js` somewhere else? They just need to be out of direct view, so there's less chance of developers modifying them. I thought of "app", but I'm not sure whether that has "special meaning" to ExtJS, and it looks kind of silly with `app/app/`:

```
app/
    app/
        X.js
        Y.js
    model/
    store/
    view/
    Application.js
```

2) Is there a recommended name for folders containing classes derived from `Ext.app.Application`?

3) Can I put them in a "hidden" folder, e.g. one starting with "."?

```
app/
    .js/
        X.js
        Y.js
    model/
    store/
    view/
    Application.js
```

4) Do I need to add any config information to the build process?

Comment: Where ever you put the files, after build app, there will be merge into on app.js file.
Are you try to hide those x, y files from your own developers?

Comment: Maybe you would like to use [Sencha Cmd Packages](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.5.3/guides/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html)?

Comment: @WaqarHaider - Yes, they can even go in a subdirectory under app, just out of direct sight. If I could put them under app/.js/,that would be great. But I can't find the config setting or whatever I need to get them to be included in the build process.

Comment: @scebotari66 - We don't want anything complicated. Why would it be so hard to just move some files into subdirectories and have them included in the build process? It seems to work for any other kinds of files, but not for application ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First. The best solution for you would be probably to move these things into separate package http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.5.3/guides/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html as it was pointed out.** It could be little bit time demanding to do so. But because I don't really understand your situation let me talk about the way you would like to have it.

> 1) Can I put X.js and Y.js somewhere else? They just need to be out of
>   direct view, so there's less chance of developers modifying them.

You can put them anywhere you want. But I don't understand the point about other people "modifying" them. Just put a comment on top of these files that they can't edit them. And because you are using **version control** (right?) the modification to them will never go pass the **code reviews**.

> 2) Is there a recommended name for folders containing classes derived
>   from Ext.app.Application?

I am not aware of that. You can name it anyway you want. But see bellow my note about class naming and their folders.

> 3) Can I put them in a "hidden" folder, e.g. one starting with "."?

Yes you can. But keep in mind that `.folders` are not really hidden. It works only on Linux and Mac by default. Not on Windows. And if I am not mistaken most IDEs will show these folders anyway.  It's implemented just in file explorers that these files are "hidden".

> 4) Do I need to add any config information to the build process?

It depends. If you have everything under the `app` folder, it should work out of the box for you. Otherwise you might need to do edits to `app.json` file.

---

So let's assume you would like to have them in a different place. Not even in the `app` folder. Let's assume the folder named "hidden" which is directly in the project root.

```
MyApp/
   .hidden/
   app/
   ext/
   ...
```

[image]

In this folder we can have any class or files as necessary.

The `MyApp/app/Application.js` file would than look like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'MyApp.Master',

});
```

To make this work take a look at the `MyApp/app.json` file which is the main "settings" file for any Sencha Cmd project. There we need to add note about class path for Cmd to be able to find these files:

```
"classpath": [
    "app",
    ".hidden"
],
```

Now the project should build without any problems. If you want to do any other modifications take a look also into app.js which is the main entry point into your project.

I tested this with Ext 6 Classic and Cmd 6.5.1

**Naming conventions:**

When specifying classes, the dots in the classname should also define the file location. So when you have this class: `MyApp.view.main.Main` one would expect to find it in the folder `MyApp/app/view/main/Main.js` but it's not necessary, you can have them all in one folder and Cmd will handle it for you. But I would expect than when you will start moving files into some "hidden" folders it won't be that clear anymore.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I moved `X.js` and `Y.js` under `app/aux` to test, and added `app/aux` under `classpath` in `app.json`. Deep clean, including deleting `build`, then build. Its coming up with `http://localhost:1841/app/Y.js?_dc=1525557485070 404 (Not Found)` so it's still not looking in `app/aux`.

Comment: Well you have something wrong in your app. You don't need to specify it int he app json when you have it in the `app` folder. Check the sources tab in dev tools. Also which versions of Ext and Cmd are you using ?

Comment: Ext JS 6.5.1.345 and Sencha Cmd v6.5.1.240. I don't know what is "sources tab in dev tools", does this correspond to a directory or an entry in a config file?

Comment: I mean "Sources" tab in the Chrome dev tools. You can take a look which JS files are loaded. Also try to create a full build not only app watch. Is there the same problem? I think you have another problem in your app, it might be hard to resolve/debug it here in the comments on the SO. I recommend registering and asking on the slack group http://www.senchatalk.com/ , there is a lot of ExtJS devs who might hint what could be wrong.

Comment: Turns out the build process has been heavily customized, so apparently new directories aren't recognized (!). I've escalated the issue to higher ups, let them deal with it. I'll still give you the points, because the question turned out to have no resolution available to yours truly.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks anyway :)